# Eclipse use make command to generate binary file

Tags: c, eclipse, makefile, arm

I am setting up Eclipse for embedded C development on an ARM CortexM board (STM32F4 Discovery), using Yagarto tools, OpenOCD, CDT, etc. My starting reference library is the following:

https://github.com/emusan/stm32f4-template

I have imported it and am able to build the project. However Eclipse does not recognize errors, and moreover, does not call `make` to generate `main.bin`:

[image: Screenshot of problems in Eclipse]

How can I rectify this? I know that if I open a terminal (MinGW, I am using Windows 7) and run `make` in the project directory, a `main.bin` file is generated. But I can't seem to get Eclipse to do this automatically.

Answer (score 1):

Open the project properties and see what's under the command in c-c++->build,
It might be that the command is not there or the path is wrong

Regarding the errors, in the properties go to build->settings and choose the error parser you wish to be used, or create one (creating is done in window->preferences->c c++->build->settings